# How to properly end a ARView that uses a Reality Composer project?

Tags: swift, xcode, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

My project has a few views before it call a ARview with a reality composer project. I enabled the coaching view in it using the demo code that apple provides. My problem is. If I make a button to go back from that view and call it again, the camera starts to flick from second to second. If I do it again, the flick increases until that, if I do it again, the program crashes. How can I make that view completely new, like the first time I loaded it? I’ve tried removing the anchor from the view.session. Tried pausing the ar session. Could anyone help me with that? 
This is my code

```
import UIKit
import RealityKit
import ARKit

class ARHomeViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var arView: ARView!
    @IBOutlet weak var coachingOverlay: ARCoachingOverlayView!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        presentCoachingOverlay()

        addScene()
    }

    /// Begins the coaching process that instructs the user's movement during
    /// ARKit's session initialization.
    func presentCoachingOverlay() {
        coachingOverlay.session = arView.session
        coachingOverlay.delegate = self
        coachingOverlay.goal = .horizontalPlane
        coachingOverlay.activatesAutomatically = false
        self.coachingOverlay.setActive(true, animated: true)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        // Prevent the screen from being dimmed to avoid interuppting the AR experience.
        UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        arView?.session.pause()
    }

    func addScene()
    {
        guard let anchor = try? ExperienciaCasa.loadMenu() else { return }

        anchor.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)

        arView.scene.addAnchor(anchor)
    }

}
```